# remove multi-line patterns

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

The original test file:

```
[root@scspr2056449018 ~]# cat test.txt
abc
def
hij
klmn
```

Tried to delete the lines containing pattern `abc\ndef`, but it doesn't work:

```
[root@scspr2056449018 ~]# sed -i 's/abc\ndef//' test.txt
[root@scspr2056449018 ~]# cat test.txt
abc
def
hij
klmn
[root@scspr2056449018 ~]# sed -i '/abc\ndef/d' test.txt
[root@scspr2056449018 ~]# cat test.txt
abc
def
hij
klmn
```

What's wrong with my use of `sed`? Or, am I using the wrong command, since `sed` is a line editor and can't match multi-line patterns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do things with the hold buffer in `sed`, but it's easier to work around that with `-z` in GNU sed to tell it to use the NUL byte as a separator instead of a newline:

```
$ sed -z 's/abc\ndef//' test.txt

hij
klmn
```

or just switch to Perl (`-0` would use the NUL as line separator, `-0777` tells it read the whole file in one go):

```
$ perl -0777 -pe 's/abc\ndef//' test.txt

hij
klmn
```

Comment: It works! But I am still hazy on why `-z` works. From the manual, it looks to `separate lines by NUL characters`. Could you elaborate a little bit on how it works, please? Does it separate `abc\ndef` into two patterns, and run `sed` on each of them?

Comment: @QiangXu, NUL is the byte with all bits zeroed. It's used as a string terminator C and the system call interfaces, so it also works to unambiguously separate filenames in lists. That's why it's supported by things like `find -print0`, and `sed -z`. Here, if your input is a text file, it should't have any NULs in it, so `sed -z` would just work to treat the whole file as a single line. (Note, don't confuse NUL with the _character_ `0`, that one is the byte with numerical value 48.)